# PCA for features selection

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

i'm dealing with Isolation Forest for APT classification and it gets encouraging results. 
Now i'm trying to improve the performance with feature selection, and i consider PCA approach.

```
df = pd.read_csv("features_labeled_PULITOIsolationFor.csv")
apt_list = list(set(df.apt))[1:]  ## Il primo è nan quindi lo scarto

for apt_name in apt_list:
   out_file = open("test.txt","a")
   out_file.write(apt_name + "\n" + "\n")
   out_file.close()
   df_apt17 = df[df["apt"] == apt_name]
   df_other = df[df["apt"] != apt_name]
   nf = 150
   pca = PCA(n_components=nf)
   df_apt17 = pca.fit_transform(df_apt17.drop("apt", 1))
   print(df_apt17.shape)
   kf = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
   df_apt17 = df_apt17.reset_index()
   df_other = df_other.reset_index()
```

After this, i perform Cross Validation dividing the apt in question in Kfolder and i use df_other dataframe for testing folder merged with some elements of current APT.

However, although PCA seems to work since the reduction of features (seen by .shape on dataframe), it gives me error on the reset_index() function:

*df_apt17 = df_apt17.reset_index()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'reset_index'*

how can i deal with this problem?

Thanks to everyone

Comment: df_apt17 is not pandas dataframe anymore after you apply the PCA.
It is internally converted into numpy array. reset_index() is an pandas dataframe function. It makes no sense for array and you should be able to simply drop it.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the docs in sklearn (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) it say that the method pca.fit_transform() return an array.

Arrays don't have reset_index() method, only pandas.DataFrame.

> **fit_transform(X, y=None)**
>
> Fit the model with X and apply the dimensionality reduction on X.
>
> **Parameters**:    X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
>
> Training data, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features
>   is the number of features.
>
> **y** : Ignored.
>
> **Returns**:   X_new : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_components)

If you need to use reset_index(), you need transform it back to a pandas.DataFrame.